# Local modifications to /etc/pam.d/common-*, not updating

Tags: dual-boot, 18.10, pam, pam-environment

Just like any normal day, I ran "***sudo apt upgrade***", but it gave me this:

```
Local modifications to /etc/pam.d/common-*, not updating.
pam-auth-update: Run pam-auth-update --force to override.
```

What should I do here?
I did run *"`pam-auth-update --force`"* command, but I don't know what to do here:
[image: What should I do in this screenshot image condition?]

Comment: Copy/paste terminal output. Please don't provide terminal output via images.

Comment: Why, when u can't see all "necessary thing"? @DKBose I think "moderator" don't like big terminal output. They might downgrade this post so, i didn't do that.

Comment: Read https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/8713/why-do-people-post-screenshots-of-their-terminals/16669#16669

Comment: @DKBose well i pasted terminal output without reading link u shared. Because it was to long to read. But i don't like this huge out mess that i pasted! (I managed to remove some of it..)